# How to scroll to a certain element of a sibling component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm quite new to ReactJS and I need a bit of guidance :

I've got a ReactJs/Vite App that fetches and lists countries in alphabetical order.

I added a side nav with the alphabet in form of clickable elements.
When a certain letter is clicked I want my app to scroll to the first country that start with that letter.

Right now my "SideNav" and "ListCountries" components are sibling of their parent "App"

App:

```
  function App() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/europe')
            .then((data) => data.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setCountries(data);
                 //do stuff..
                }
            });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div className='row h-25 w-100 ps-5'>
              //Component displaying the alphabet
                {alphabet &&
                    alphabet.map((letter) => (
                        <CardAlphabet
                            letter={alphabet}
                        />
                    )
                )}
            </div>
            <ul>
               //Component displaying the countries in an alphabetical order
                {countries &&
                    countries.map((country, id) => (
                        key={id}
                        <Country
                            id={id}
                            name={country.name.common}
                        />
                    )
                )}
            </ul>
                    
        </div>
    );
}
```

CardAlphabet Component :

```
export default function CardAlphabet(props) {
    return (
        <div className='col-lg-2'>
            <span
                className='some-classes'>
                {props.letter}
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Country Component:

```
    import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import { useInView } from 'framer-motion';
    import { useCountryStore } from './Cards/Store';
    import classNames from 'classnames';
    
    export const Country = (props) => {
        const ref = useRef();
        const isInView = useInView(ref, { margin: '-50% 0px -50% 0px' });
        const id = props.id;
        const countryStore = useCountryStore();
        const firstLetter = props.dataFirstLetter;
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (isInView) {
                countryStore.setInViewCountry(id);
            }
            if (!isInView && countryStore.inViewCountry === id) {
                countryStore.setInViewCountry(null);
            }
        }, [isInView, id]);
    
//The HandleClick  is to be able to click on ever country to scroll it into view, so not related to the problem 
        const handleClick = () => {
            ref.current?.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'center',
                inline: 'center',
            });
        };
    
        return (
            <li
                onClick={handleClick}
                ref={ref}
                datafirstletter={firstLetter}
                className={classNames(
                    'some-classes' + props.id,
                    isInView ? 'text-active' : ''
                )}>
                
                <p className={classNames(isInView ? 'text-active' : '')}>{props.name}</p>
            </li>
        );
    };
```

There's a bit of unrelated stuff to the problem, but since i use Zustand, maybe its gonna be helpful(?)

Im sorry i didn't know what to keep and what to show from my code.
don't hesitate to tell me if i put too much.

I tried adding data-attr to each country with their first letter but how would I access that from the sibling  and how would I scrollTo a certain data-attr?

I need your guidance of how to approach that problem

### SOLVED

I solved my issue!
By deducing the first letter of each country, and passing it as a data in the country component :

```
export const Country = (props) => {
return (
        <li
            data-first-letter={firstLetter}
            className="some-classes">
            //Country Name
        </li>
    );
};
```

and adding an onClick as a prop

```
function App() {
function scrollToFirstLetter(a) {
        const child = document.querySelector(`[data-first-letter='${a}']`);
        if (child) {
            child.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'center',
                inline: 'center',
            });
        }
    }
}
return(
       <CardAlphabet
         onClick={() => scrollToFirstLetter(letter)}
         letter={letter}
         presentLetter={presentSubNames}
        />

)
```

I can access the the letter on the nav clicked and the first letter of each country. So  I can logically scroll to the corresponding first element

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Done! dont hesitate to tell me if its enough or not